# Cross-worksheet formulas in evaluate() in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to calculate conditional max of the ith column in a sheet called "Data" when the corresponding value in column A of sheet "Data" falls in a range from another sheet "Result". I tried to use the code below but it's wrong:

```
Worksheets("Result").Cells(r , 4)=Evaluate("=STDEV(IF(Data!A:A>=Result!range(r,1) and Data!A:A<Result!range(r,2),Data!columns(i)))")
```

What's the correct way to write the formula?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing your strings and variables. VBA methods won't magically execute in the middle of strings - you need to execute them separately and concatenate back in. There's also no "and" like that in Excel - you either mean for it to be executed in VBA, or you need to use it like a function `And(condition1, condition2)`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't remember the and() function correctly. I just cannot find out how to correctly concatenate strings and variables.

Comment: In columns(i) is `i` a variable or are you want column I

Comment: Work on getting the formula correct in the sheet first: when that's working edit your question to include it so we can see what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the vba parts from the string and concatenated with `&`.

And array formulas do not work well with And instead use the * to compare the two boolean values.

```
Worksheets("Result").Cells(r,4)=Worksheets("Result").Evaluate("=STDEV(IF((Data!A:A>=Result!" & Cells(r,1).Address & ")*(Data!A:A<Result!" & Cells(r,2).Address & "),Data!" & columns(i).Address & "))")
```

***WARNING:***  You are using full column references in an Array formula.  If you have too many loops this will be slow.  It is better to change all the full column references to the extents of the dataset.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks. As you point our, it is a bit too slow. I'm wondering what you mean by "change all the full column references to the extents of the dataset"?

Comment: See @ThomasInzina answer.  He shows one method.  You need to find the extents of the data in columns A and the Column that is referenced by the variable i and set it to that.  like A2:A100 and so forth.  Or at least set the range to range just large enough to ensure a capture of all the data like A2:A1000.

Answer (score 2):

Taking Scott Craner's advice, I use Intersect to trim the column ranges down to fit the actual data.

Here is the sample output where `r = 10: i = 5` and `Worksheets("Data")` has 19 rows of data:

`=STDEV(IF((Data!$A$1:$A$19>=Result!$A$10)*Data!$A$1:$A$19<Result!$B$10),Data!@$E$1:$E$19))`

Declare the new variables:

```
Dim DataA As String, DataI As String, sFormula As String
```

The code to insert into the `i` and `r` loops:

```
With Worksheets("Data")
    DataA = Intersect(.Columns("A"), .UsedRange).Address
    DataI = Intersect(.Columns(i), .UsedRange).Address
    sFormula = "=STDEV(IF((Data!" & DataA & ">=Result!$A$" & r & ")*(Data!" & DataA & "<Result!$B$" & r & "),Data!@" & DataI & "))"
End With

With Worksheets("Result")
    .Cells(r, 4) = .Evaluate(sFormula)
End With
```

Comment: @ScottCraner I made DataA a string and assigned it the range's address; so that I  could shorten the concatenation: `Intersect(.Columns("A"), .UsedRange).Address`.   I think that I got it right.  Can you can double check the sample output string that I provided?

Comment: Sorry missed that, I was on my phone.

Comment: @ScottCraner no worries.  It was a little sneaky.